# How can I send Ctrl + "`" in advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I am trying to write the equivalent of the following in advanced scripting:

[image]

I tried:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "^`"
    Wait(1)
    SendKeys "2"
End Sub
```

But [`SendKeys "^`"`](http://www.exaq.com/DNS/QR10/ScriptingReference.html#VB-SendKeys) doesn't seem to have the same effect as the first line of the step-by-step voice command, which I don't understand.

The goal is to retrieve the second element in [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) clipboard history.

[image]

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-send-Ctrl-+-%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9D-in-advanced-scripting